# Recursive Addition in Lisp

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp, addition

I'm a beginner and I am trying to teach myself Common Lisp and during my self-study I have written a function that I believe should work for recursive addition of two arguments. However, the function always fails. Why is that?

```
(defun sum (n m)
  ;;;Returns the sum of n and m using recursion
  (cond ((eq m 0) n))
  (sum (1+ n) (1- m)))
```

As I understand it, it should continually add 1 to n while decrementing m until m is 0 at which point, the recursive addition is complete

Comment: You call `SUM` recursively. It stops when the stack overflows. Maybe you should improve the condition to stop it calling itself... Try using `IF`. Also `EQ` is not for numbers. Use `EQL` or `=`.

Comment: The indentation is correct according to the code. `cond` does something that is thrown away (`n` or `nil`) then unconditional recurse by adding `n` and reducing `m`. It won't return `nil` since it won't halt. You do get a stack overflow message right?

Comment: @Sylwester Yes, I get a stack overflow message in Emacs. Studying what others have corrected me on showed me how I actually messed up with  my cond statement and why the recursion never ends.

Answer (score 5):

It's really wierd use case to do such addition, but I'll explain you where is your mistakes:

```
(defun sum (n m)
  ;;;Returns the sum of n and m using recursion
  (cond ((eq m 0) n)) ;; <= This line is ignored, you not returnin N.
  (sum (1+ n) (1- m))) ;; <= this will be called forever
```

You should write:

```
(defun sum (n m)
  "Recursively increment N and decrement M untill M = 0"
  (if (= m 0) ;; don't use EQ for numbers, use EQL or =.
    n
    (sum (1+ n) (1- m)))) ;; Otherwise recursive call
```

Let's trace it to see how it works:

```
CL-USER> (sum 0 10) 
  0: (SUM 0 10)
    1: (SUM 1 9)
      2: (SUM 2 8)
        3: (SUM 3 7)
          4: (SUM 4 6)
            5: (SUM 5 5)
              6: (SUM 6 4)
                7: (SUM 7 3)
                  8: (SUM 8 2)
                    9: (SUM 9 1)
                      10: (SUM 10 0)
                      10: SUM returned 10
                    9: SUM returned 10
                  8: SUM returned 10
                7: SUM returned 10
              6: SUM returned 10
            5: SUM returned 10
          4: SUM returned 10
        3: SUM returned 10
      2: SUM returned 10
    1: SUM returned 10
  0: SUM returned 10
10
```

If you'll take an advice - don't try to do such weird things with recursion, if you want to leard how to use it, try it for some natural-recursive cases like factorials, fibonacci, tree processing and such.

Comment: or at least align `cond` test forms to each other. The error could easily be spotted if cond wasn't on the same level as recursive call to sum.

Comment: Of course he can use cond, but if you have onli two branches if is idiomatic.

Comment: Yes, clearly if would be more idiomatic here. Just mentioning cond in case OP gets into similar problems in some other case, where cond would be idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm understanding Lisp a lot better and can see why my code was failing. And I'll certainly take your advice and stick to more naturally recursive problems :)

Comment: The OP's use-case is a standard text-book example of using recursion to build up primitive operations in university computability courses.

Comment: @galdre, may be you right. I was studing philosophy, so I'm not very familiar with standard text-book examples in this courses.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have 2 simple typos:

1. one parenthesis too many and
2. missing `t` in your `cond` clause.

What you probably meant was:

```
(defun sum (n m)
  (cond 
   ((eq m 0) n)               ; here you had one parenthesis too many
   (t (sum (1+ n) (1- m)))))  ; here you were missing the `t` symbol
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought my code was just completely wrong but it is a little encouraging to see that I was 2 small typos away from having something working.

Comment: @BurnedOut No you were pretty close. While I would also use `if` rather than `cond` here, some people recommend to *always* use `cond` for various reasons, such as the [Racket style guide](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/Style/style/Choosing_the_Right_Construct.html#%28part._.Conditionals%29).